# Number of Linearly Dependent Rows/Columns and Number of Zero Eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank

> The rank of a matrix is the maximum number of independent rows (or, the maximum number of independent columns).
>   A square matrix $A_{~ n ~ \times ~ n}$ is non-singular only if its rank is equal to n.
>   [*Source*](http://chortle.ccsu.edu/vectorlessons/vmch16/vmch16_15.html)

Consider a quadratic matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{~ n ~ \times ~ n}$

- with **in total** $p$ linearly dependent rows (or columns) and otherwise no zero-rows/-columns, which equals to $n-(p-1)$ linearly independent rows/columns, e.g.

$$A_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 5 & 0 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\ 9 & 8 & 0 & 7 & 6 \end{bmatrix} \quad \rightarrow \quad n = 5, ~ p = 2; ~ n-(p-1) = 4$$
$$ \hookrightarrow \lambda_1 = 0; ~ \lambda_2, \lambda_3, \lambda_4, \lambda_5 \neq 0 \quad \rightarrow ~ Rank(A_1) = 4$$

$$A_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \quad \rightarrow \quad n = 5, ~ p = 2; ~ n-(p-1) = 4$$
$$ \hookrightarrow \lambda_1 = 0; ~ \lambda_2, \lambda_3, \lambda_4, \lambda_5 \neq 0 \quad \rightarrow ~ Rank(A_2) = 4$$

- ***or*** with **exactly** $p-1$ zero-rows/-columns and otherwise $n-(p-1)$ linearly independent rows/columns, e.g.

$$A_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 5 & 0 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\ 9 & 8 & 0 & 7 & 6 \end{bmatrix} \quad \rightarrow \quad n = 5, ~ (p-1) = 1; ~ n-(p-1) = 4$$
$$ \hookrightarrow \lambda_1 = 0; ~ \lambda_2, \lambda_3, \lambda_4, \lambda_5 \neq 0 \quad \rightarrow ~ Rank(A_3) = 4$$

$$A_4 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \quad \rightarrow \quad n = 5, ~ (p-1) = 1; ~ n-(p-1) = 4$$
$$ \hookrightarrow \lambda_1 = 0; ~ \lambda_2, \lambda_3, \lambda_4, \lambda_5 \neq 0 \quad \rightarrow ~ Rank(A_4) = 4$$

Are the following statements true?

- $det(A) = 0$
- The rank of $A$ is $rank(A) \leq n-(p-1)$, $rank(A) = n-m = k$,
  $m$ being the number/multiplicity of zero-eigenvalues and
  $k$ the number of non-zero-eigenvalues (counting multiplicity).
  *Or should it be $rank(A) = n-(p-1) = n-m = k$?*
- The multiplicity of zero as an eigenvalue is **at least** $p-1$ (*or should it be **exactly** $p-1$?*), i.e.

  - $\lambda_1 = 0$
  - $\dots$
  - $\lambda_{p-1} = 0$
  - $\lambda_{p} = ~ ?$
  - $\dots$
  - $\lambda_{n} = ~ ?$

Comment: What do you mean by "**exactly** $p$ linearly dependent rows"? If any $p$ of the rows are linearly dependent, then all $n$ rows are linearly dependent. Do you mean that $p$ is the least integer such that there are $p$ linearly dependent rows?

Comment: @joriki Is the edited question clearer and are the formulations mathematically correct? Being an engineer, I did not understand your comment, specifically "If any $p$ of the rows are linearly dependent, then all n rows are linearly dependent.".

Comment: @joriki It's easy to make an example of a three element linearly dependent set where any two elements for a linearly independent set: consider $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$ and $(1,1,0)$.

Comment: @egreg: That's certainly true. Were you implying that this contradicts something I wrote? If so, what?

Comment: @user5564832: Unfortunately it hasn't become any clearer to me -- "**in total** $p$ linearly dependent rows" makes as little sense to me as the previous formulation. Could you spell out what you mean?

Comment: @joriki No, the remark was aimed to pointing out that neither the maximum nor the minimum number have a real usefulness.

Comment: @joriki For me, A = [1, 0, 0; 1, 0, 0; 0, 1 0] has *in total* $p=2$ linearly *dependent* rows (the first two), and therefore $n-(p-1) = 3-(2-1) = 2$ linearly *independent* rows; Hence the rank is 2 and the multiplicity of 0 as an eigenvalue is only 1 and **not** $p=2$

Comment: @user5564832: I don't understand what that means. That matrix also has $3$ linearly dependent rows (all three rows). If I write a matrix with more rows, it may have various sets of dependent rows of various sizes. I don't know what you mean by forming the "total" of these sizes. It would be good if you could give a definition of that term rather than further examples.

Comment: @joriki How is the third row $[0, 1, 0]$ linearly dependent of the other two identical rows (first and second) $[1, 0, 0]$ considering the matrix $A = [1, 0, 0; 1, 0, 0; 0, 1, 0]$? Unfortunately, I cannot give a definition other than the examples, so I would understand your surrender before my ignorance.

Comment: @user5564832: A set of vectors is defined to be linearly dependent if the zero vector can be formed as a linear combination of the vectors in the set other than by choosing all coefficients zero. It's clear from this definition that any superset of a linearly dependent set of vectors is linearly dependent.

Answer (score 2):

The “maximum number of linearly dependent rows” doesn't really make sense. Consider the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The three rows form a linearly dependent set, but no subset of rows is linearly dependent.

What you can define is the maximum number of linearly independent rows, which in the above case is $2$. Such number is the *rank* of the matrix.

By the rank-nullity theorem, if $k$ is the rank, $n-k$ is the dimension of the null space of the matrix, which is the *geometric multiplicity* of the eigenvalue $0$ (provided $0$ is an eigenvalue to begin with, that is, $k<n$).

The algebraic multiplicity of the zero eigenvalue is *at least* $n-k$. It can be bigger: consider
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
For this matrix, the algebraic multiplicity of the zero eigenvalue is $2$, but the geometric multiplicity is $1$.

A matrix is non-singular if and only if $0$ is not an eigenvalue, essentially by definition of eigenvalue (together with the rank-nullity theorem): $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix $A$ if and only if $A-\lambda I$ is singular.

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}$If I understand, you're asking:

> Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ (real/complex) matrix with $k < n$ non-zero eigenvalues (counting multiplicity) and $m \geq 1$ the multiplicity of $0$ as an eigenvalue.
>
> - Is $\det A = 0$?
> - Is $\rank A = n - m = k$, the number of non-zero eigenvalues counted with multiplicity, or only $\rank A \geq n - m$?

To the first, Yes: $0$ is an eigenvalue.

For the second: If $A$ has $k$ non-zero eigenvalues, then the column space of $A$ clearly has dimension at least $k$, so $\rank A \geq n - m$. Equality, however, fails to hold in the "worst possible sense": An $n \times n$ matrix of rank $(n - 1)$ can have *every eigenvalue equal to $0$*; a [Jordan block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_matrix) with $\lambda = 0$ has this property.

Comment: Should those $\geq$ not rather be $\leq$ ?

Comment: Actually not: The rank is bounded _below_ by the number of non-zero eigenvalues. Again, a matrix of "large" rank can fail to have any non-zero eigenvalues at all.